# Is there a fast way to match my "cell content" to the "row number"

Tags: excel, sorting

Is there a fast way to match my "cell content" to the "row number"?

[image]

Ex: the ones with the yellow Highlight

my "cell content" 326 matches with the "row number" 326
my cell content 337, matches with the row number 337

I want to do the same thing with cell contents 350, 353, 361, 365, 372, 380, 385, 389, 397, 402, 409 and 411 easily

Comment: just use, `=row()`

Answer (score 0):

User simple command in conditional formatting,

[image: condForm]

Comment: Please inform if more clarification is required